# Widgets inverse when I run App - android studio

Tags: android, android-studio

I use android studio and the GUI Designer

when I run the app I see TextView in the left but i put it right in GUI Designer same with ImageView

[In GUI Designer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zEiCS.png)

[In mobile (I've tried 2 devices with diff System Versions)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cByCH.png)

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="horizontal" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:weightSum="1">
<ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/imageView"
    android:src="@drawable/celebi"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:contentDescription="@string/celebi_picture" />
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/txt_detail"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:textSize="18sp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/imageView"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/imageView"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageView" />
```

this GridLayout also inverse things !

```
<GridLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="150dp"
    android:layout_height="150dp"
    android:id="@+id/txt_detail"
    android:layout_row="0"
    android:layout_column="1" />

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="150dp"
    android:layout_height="150dp"
    android:id="@+id/imageView"
    android:layout_row="0"
    android:layout_column="2"
    android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />
```

this LinearLayout same thing :

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="150dp"
    android:layout_height="150dp"
    android:id="@+id/txt_detail"
    android:layout_row="0"
    android:layout_column="1" />

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="150dp"
    android:layout_height="150dp"
    android:id="@+id/imageView"
    android:layout_row="0"
    android:layout_column="2"
    android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />
```

Answer (score 1):

You're using `layout_alignParentRight` and `layout_alignParentEnd`. These can be different on different versions of Android since older version don't support RTL languages. It will also change based on the whether language set on the device is RTL or not.

-=Edit=-

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:src="@drawable/celebi"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:contentDescription="@string/celebi_picture" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txt_detail"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageView" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: In Linear Layout I Tried this :
 <ImageView
        android:layout_width="144dp"
        android:layout_height="144dp"
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:src="@drawable/mew" /> same problem! 
so what should i do if LinearLayout and this make problems

Comment: I'm putting some XML in my answer. Try that and see if it works.

Answer (score 0):

replace this code

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
    android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/txt_detail"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/imageView"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageView"
    android:text="asfsksdgk"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:textSize="18sp"
    android:textStyle="bold" />
```

Comment: still same problem

Answer (score 0):

Write this line in Androidmanifest.xml

```
<application
    android:supportsRtl="true"/>
```

This works for me.